# how to bind multiple images to figure element with knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, figure

i want generate below output with knockoutjs.

```
<figure data-bind="?">
<img src="a.jpg" />
<img src="b.jpg" />
<img src="c.jpg" />
......
.......
<figcaption>Image title</figcaption>
</figure>
```

there are many `<img />` elements and only one `figcaption`.

how to write the data-bind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create observable array, like this:

```
var A = (function() {
    function A()
    {
        this.images = ko.observableArray(['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg']);
    }

    return A;
})();

ko.applyBindings(new A());
```

And the HTML:

```
<figure>
    <!-- ko foreach: images -->
        <img data-bind="attr: {src: $data}">
    <!-- /ko -->
    <figcaption>Image title</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j346v/1/).

Comment: the `div` is nessary? i don't want to wrap the images with the `div`, if i want use `foreach` , a outer wrapper element(eg. `div`,`ul`) is nessary?